# AsyncResult class with a constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iasyncresult

I am looking to instantiating an AsyncResult object but there seems to be no AsyncResult class  with a constructor in .Net Frameowork that I can instantiate.

Can someone provide a ready implementation of IAsynResult interface in C#? Or is there some trick way to instantiate an AsyncResult object?

**Edit 1:** 
I am creating an async task within an ASP.Net page. In the begin method, I call a data layer static method called 'AsyncBeginGetSummary'.

**I would normally use ADO.Net BeginExecuteReader within this static method, which would work perfectly and I wouldn't need to instantiate an AsyncResult object.** But, if the data object exists in Cache in ASP.Net app, then from this static method of ''AsyncBeginGetSummary', I do not want to call BeginExecuteReader.

But then, I still need to return AsyncResult object so the End method of the task in ASP.Net can be called. My ASP.Net page code is like below.

```
 IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation1(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb,
                                                           object state)
    {
         //call a static method from DAL that returns IAsyncResult.
         //call 'AsyncBeginGetSummary' static method in DAL
    }

    void EndAsyncOperation1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //call a static method in DAL that gets your data here 
        //call 'AsyncEndGetSummary' static method in DAL
    }
```

**Edit 2:** 
I have the following where I do not need to bother about instantiating AsyncResult object since I use a dummy method delegate to call BeginInvoke.

```
 IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation1(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
         //call a static method from DAL that return IAsyncResult. 
         if((Cache["abc"] !=null)
         {
             return (new dummy(DummyMethod)).BeginInvoke(cb, new FinalDataForDocumentsSummary(listFromCache.Count, listFromCache));
         } 

        return NFM.Data.Mappers.DocumentsSummaryByProgramDataMapper.AsyncBeginEndDocumentsSummaryByProgramAll( vendorId, cb);

    }

    void EndAsyncOperation1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //call a static method in DAL that gets your data here

    }



    public delegate void dummy();

    private void DummyMethod()
    {
    }
```

**Edit 3:** I have used the following AsyncResult implementation in WCF. I guess I could use it in ASP.Net also.

```
 class AsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
{
    private T data;
    private object state;
    private bool isCompleted = false;
    private AutoResetEvent waitHandle;
    private bool isSynchronous = false;

    public T Data
    {
        set { data = value; }
        get { return data; }
    }

    public AsyncResult(bool synchronous, object stateData)
    {
        isSynchronous = synchronous;
        state = stateData;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        isCompleted = true;
        ((AutoResetEvent)AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return state; }
    }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            if (waitHandle == null)
                waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            return waitHandle;
        }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isCompleted)
                return false;
            else
                return isSynchronous;
        }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return isCompleted; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should almost never need to create your own `IAsyncResult`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikos/archive/2011/03/14/how-to-implement-iasyncresult-in-another-way.aspx, but you probably should not be doing this.

Comment: Please see Edit 1 under my post for what I am after. I think I could return a null for AsyncResult if the data is in cache rather tha instantiate AsyncResult object.

Comment: I've gone down this path, and found it rather painful. You probably should re-think your approach, as there are easier ways to do this. In my particular situation, a Task made quick work of it. But even an asynchronous delegate would probably do what you want.

Comment: @JimMischel is right.  Using the `Task` class will make this _much_ simpler.  (`return Task.FromResult(...)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want an `IAsyncResult` that indicates synchronous completion – that the result is already available.

In that case, you can create your own simple class that returns `true` for `IsCompleted` and `CompletedSynchronously`, and returns the caller's parameter in `AsyncState`, and `null` for `WaitHandle`.

If you want the caller to be able to use the `WaitHandle`, you'll need to create a `ManualResetEvent` and dispose it at some point; see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx).

Comment: SLaks - Thanks. Do you have a sample implementation?

Comment: The implementations I linked to are much more complicated, since they deal with non-completed operations.

Comment: How about just calling BeginInvoke on dummy method I create. This method could be called 'DummyMethod()' This will get the asyncresult object. Right? the callback will the callback I would pass to BeginExecuteReader. This seems ok to me.

Comment: SLaks- Thanks.  Which of my Edit 2 or Edit 3 solutions appears better in my situation according to you?

Comment: @Sunil: Edit 2 is less efficient; Edit 3 leaks WaitHandles (which is bad).  If you want to create WaitHandles, see my linked articles.